# Pig doesn't clean /tmp directory files when ran through Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I am running an Oozie coordinator job continuously on daily basis. 
The coordinator  triggers workflow jobs with a frequency of 1440 (i.e 24 hours).
The workflow is a simple data pipeline which pulls some external data using **Java actions** , processes them using **Pig Actions** and then **Sqoop** out the processed  data to an external DB.

It was working fine for the last two months. 
However, I recently noticed that the cluster is running low on Disk Space. 
As a consequence, i checked HDFS and to my surprise, I found that the **/tmp** directory size is 3 times the **/user** directory.

When i digged into the **/tmp** directory, i found that a few of the previous workflow jobs temp working directories are still residing inside the **/tmp** directory. I think these directories should get cleaned once the jobs are completed (irrespectively of the final state of the job).

I have manually deleted a few large directories and now, the disk space issue is resolved.
However, I wanted to understand why not all of the temp directories are getting erased, any ideas why ?

Below are the cluster details :

- Hadoop Distribution : Cloudera (CDH 4.8)
- Total nodes : 6
- Name Node :1
- Secondary Name node :1
- Data Nodes : 4
- Disk space per node : 500 GB

Below are the **fs -du** results :

```
bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -du -h /
2.5 K    /hbase
217.0 G  /tmp
46.5 G   /user

Inside the /tmp :

bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -du -h /tmp
0        /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files
4        /tmp/mapred
22.9 M   /tmp/temp-100334970
4.6 M    /tmp/temp-1014433124
1.8 M    /tmp/temp-1050713307
243.7 K  /tmp/temp-1166395306
188.6 M  /tmp/temp-1243526890
11.6 M   /tmp/temp-1246394296
182.2 K  /tmp/temp-1376015266
7.2 M    /tmp/temp-1426134619
18.4 G   /tmp/temp-1490128243
527.2 M  /tmp/temp-1582569445
1.6 G    /tmp/temp-15985618
27.3 M   /tmp/temp-16966016
1.7 M    /tmp/temp-1920170181
3.6 M    /tmp/temp-194155462
190.0 G  /tmp/temp-2050991966
173.6 K  /tmp/temp-31318147
2.5 M    /tmp/temp-327605300
```

Comment: Please reformat your question, it is quite hard to understand it.

Comment: edited the question,Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Any ideas on this?